# Why does Python support both tuple and dict formatting using the percent operator in a specific case?

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples, string-formatting

This input:

```
'%s %(?)s' % {'?': 'a'}
```

results in this output:

```
"{'?': 'a'} a"
```

which replaces both the tuple-based and dict-based placeholders in the source string with the value you would expect if you used either of them alone.

However, if you reverse the placement of the placeholders in the string you get a TypeError:

```
In [2]: '%(?)s %s' % {'?': 'a'}
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-7989b5f88c97> in <module>()
----> 1 '%(?)s %s' % {'?': 'a'}

TypeError: not enough arguments for format
```

Comment: I agree. It would be more consistent if `'%s %(?)s' % {'?': 'a'}` raised an error as well. Are there many cases like this? You can use a single argument, a tuple or a dictionary as arguments to %-formatting. But it seems that the dictionary is parsed as _both_ a single argument and as a mapping.

Comment: [This caveat from the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting) might be relevant. It might be a `printf` "quirk".
_**Note** The formatting operations described here exhibit a variety of quirks that lead to a number of common errors (such as failing to display tuples and dictionaries correctly). Using the newer str.format() interface helps avoid these errors, and also provides a generally more powerful, flexible and extensible approach to formatting text._

Answer (score -1):

Each %s consumes one of the variable after the standalone % symbol.  In the first case there are two variables, the while expression and the dictionary mapping.

In the second case, the first %s takes the dictionary mapping and consumes the whole expression, has evaluated it. That leaves the second %s without a matching variable.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by the first case having two variables. The value after % is the same in both cases. What is the "while expression" you are referring to?